# Who was St. Jane of Chantal's first spiritual director?

Tags: catholicism, reference-request, saint, hagiography, jansenism

Before [St. Jane de Chantal](https://www.bartleby.com/210/8/212.html) met St. Francis de Sales, she had a very strict spiritual director,

> a priest at the nearby shrine of the Black Virgin at
> Notre-Dame-d’Etang. He undertook her direction by burdening her
> with a great many formal exercises of devotion: long vocal prayers,
> elaborate meditations and mental considerations sealed with the stipulation that she speak to no one else but him of her spiritual life.
> The rigidity and exteriority of this director’s scheme served only to
> increase her anxiety and alienate her from the drama going on
> within.
> <sub>—[*Bond of Perfection: Jeanne de Chantal & François de Sales*](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=7999), Wendy M. Wright, p. 34</sub>

Who was this "priest at the nearby shrine of the Black Virgin at Notre-Dame-d’Etang", exactly? Was he a Jansenist?